# Disabling weekend and national Holidays in ajax calendar extender control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, calendar

I have been trying to use an ajax CalenderExtender for my application.

I have many small operations in my app like adding duration to start date of a task to find the finish date, change duration of a task if its end date is changed (depending on its start date),etc.

But while I do all these operations I want to skip all the holidays and saturday , sundays from the calculations for eg. a task starting on 01/23/2014 with a duration of 5 days should finish on 01/29/2014 (adding 2 days for sat n sun in duration) instead of 01/27/2014. Same should be performed on other operations as well.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

For Sundays and Saturdays, it's easy. Just check the [`DateTime.DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your dates.

If you have an operation that will start on date `start` and will end on date `end`, you can see what dates are Saturdays or Sundays like this:

```
List<DateTime> satsAndSundays;
for (DateTime temp = start; temp <= end; temp.AddDays(1))
{
    if (temp.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ||
        temp.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        satsAndSundays.add(temp);
    }
}
```

And since you can know how many days there are between `start` and `end` by doing something like:

```
TimeSpan span = end - start;
int totalDays = (int)span.TotalDays;
// TotalDays is actually a double, I'm just discarding the non integer part.
```

You may fid out how many work days you have there by doing `totalDays - satsAndSundays.Count`.

**Edit:** I just read the question again. If you want a task to start on a given date, and take `x` work days, you can do it like this:

```
DateTime end = start;
for (int i = x; i >= 0;) // the third parameter of the for is empty on purpose
{
    end = end.AddDays(1);
    if (end.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
        end.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        i--;
    }
}
```

Afther the loop, `end` will be `x` workdays after `start` (provided there are no holidays in between).

For holidays, though, there is no alghoritm for that in the framework. You need to fetch them from some source (a file, a database, a web service etc.). Or you could write your own program to figure them out - most holidays that are not on a fixed date do follow formulas when it comes to when they happen. Do take into account, however, that holidays may vary by culture and region. If your application is to be used throughout a country, for example, it may be quite the effort to implement city-wide holidays. Depending on your needs, it might even be better to either let the users input which days are holidays, or making your own database your app can access and use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```
private string GetDatesOfSundays(DateTime DatMonth)  
    {  
        string sReturn = "";  
        int iDayOffset = DatMonth.Day - 1;  
        DatMonth = DatMonth.AddDays(System.Convert.ToDouble(-DatMonth.Day + 1));  
        DateTime DatMonth2 = DatMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(System.Convert.ToDouble(-1));  
        while (DatMonth < DatMonth2)  
        {  
            if (DatMonth.DayOfWeek == System.DayOfWeek.Sunday)  
            {  
                if (sReturn.Length > 0) sReturn += ",";  
                sReturn += DatMonth.ToShortDateString();  
            }  
            DatMonth = DatMonth.AddDays(1.0);  
        }  
        return sReturn;  
    }
```